# How to get image size in KB while using Pillow-python before storing to disk?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm using Pillow for image processing in Python,

```
url="http://www.image.com/some_image.jpg";

path = io.BytesIO(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())

original_image = Image.open(path)
```

Any idea how i can get the size of this image file using Pillow? I'd like to process the image for size **before** storing it to disk

Answer (score 5):

The answer is going to depend on what format you save the image in, so the most accurate solution would be along the lines of:

```
>>> out = io.BytesIO()
>>> original_image.save(out, format='png')
>>> out.tell()
# size in bytes
```

If you want the size of the uncompressed pixel data, you need to know how many bits are in a pixel. I don't believe this is exposed in Pillow, you'll have to lookup that value using `original_image.mode` and reference [Unpack.c](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/libImaging/Unpack.c#L1032). Then its just `width * height * bytes_per_pixel`. If your image uses a palette, it gets more complicated and I'd recommend just using the first method.

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled across this question which searching for same requirement. I tried method suggested by kalhartt but it gives me different value. Using `os.stat` seems to provide accurate value. Here is code for both methods and output.

```
from PIL import Image
import io, os

print('*** Program Started ***')

image_path_input = '/github/python-01-utilities/image/input/'
image_name_input = '20170708-sky-1873934_1920.jpg'

im = Image.open(image_path_input + image_name_input)

print(im.format, im.size, im.mode)
# print(im.getdata(),im.filename, im.width, im.height, im.info)

# im.show()
out = io.BytesIO()
im.save(out, format='png')
print('File size using io.BytesIO : ',out.tell())

print('File size using os.stat    : ',os.stat(image_path_input + image_name_input).st_size)

print('*** Program Ended ***')
```

Here is the output

```
JPEG (1920, 1285) RGB
File size using io.BytesIO :  977359
File size using os.stat    :  147162
```

Actual file size is 147.2 KB (as displayed on Ubuntu GUI). You can see, os.stat gives correct value here.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but os.stat is simply reporting the image size of the file on the disk - the OP was looking for a file size for an image object opened with Pillow.  Additionally in your code above you save 'out' as a 'PNG' as per the method shown by kalhartt but compare it to an original 'JPG' so that could explain the difference you got.  Cheers, Steve

Comment: testing with a 928864 byte **png** image, io.BytesIO says it's 924605 (4259 byte difference)